# CRC 16 for DECT in C#

Tags: c#, crc16

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289611/crc-16-dect-with-poly-x16-x10-x8-x7-x3-1) asked and answered in C, but I'm struggling a bit to achieve the same thing in C#.

Generator Polynomial : `x^16 + x^10 + x^8 + x^7 + x^3 + 1` which is equivalent to `10000010110001001` in binary.

---

I have 48 bits of data, and now I required to generate 16 bits of CRC, here's the code:

```
  private bool[] MakeCRC(string BitString)
    {
        bool[] Res = new bool[17];  
        bool[] CRC = new bool[16];
        int i;
        bool DoInvert= false;

        for (i = 0; i < 16; ++i) // Init before calculation
            CRC[i] = false;

        for (i = 0; i < BitString.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (BitString[i] == '1')
                DoInvert = true ^ CRC[15];

            //DoInvert = ('1' == BitString[i]) ^ CRC[15]; // XOR required?

            CRC[15] = CRC[14];
            CRC[14] = CRC[13];
            CRC[13] = CRC[12];
            CRC[12] = CRC[11];
            CRC[11] = CRC[10];
            CRC[10] = CRC[9] ^ DoInvert;
            CRC[9] = CRC[8];
            CRC[8] = CRC[7] ^ DoInvert;
            CRC[7] = CRC[6] ^ DoInvert;
            CRC[6] = CRC[5];
            CRC[5] = CRC[4];
            CRC[4] = CRC[3];
            CRC[3] = CRC[2] ^ DoInvert;
            CRC[2] = CRC[1];
            CRC[1] = CRC[0];
            CRC[0] = DoInvert;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
            Res[15 - i] = CRC[i] ? true : false;

        Res[16] = false; // Set string terminator

        return (Res);

    }
```

but the above code, gives me wrong output, please suggest me if there's any better way of doing it.

**`Edit:`**

Data(a0 to a47): `100011100011000001000001000100001000000000001000`

Polynomial: `10000010110001001`

Output Obtained: **`0011 0100 1111 0111`**

Output Expected: ***1100 1101 0100 1111***

---

Thanks for your time.!

Comment: "gives me wrong output" isn't really a sufficient explanation of the problem.  What parts do and don't work properly, based on your testing, provide some sample input, actual output, and expected output.  Finally, the C solutions should map pretty closely to C# code, with only minimal changes.  Why didn't you decide to map one of those working solutions you linked to more closely instead of doing something completely different?

Comment: @Servy, Thanks for the suggestion, please see the edit section, I'm still using the same method but different data types, due to pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uncomment DoInvert = ('1' == BitString[i]) ^ CRC[15]; 
and remove the line above and it works.

Your replacement for the commented line is wrong. Right would be:

```
if (BitString[i] == '1')
    DoInvert = true ^ CRC[15];
else
    DoInvert = false ^ CRC[15];
```