# strtol result mismatch while string conversion

Tags: c, arrays, string, hex, strtol

After checking out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267803/how-to-correctly-convert-a-hex-string-to-byte-array-in-c/18267932#18267932) question I did not found required solution, so I've tried to use `strtol` in following manner:

```
in = (unsigned char *)malloc(16);

for(size_t i = 0; i < (size_t)strlen(argv[2]) / 2; i+=2 )
{
    long tmp = 0;
    tmp = strtol((const char *)argv[2] + i, &argv[2] + 2, 16);
    memcpy(&in[i], &tmp, 1);
}
```

This code produced several intermediate values:

[image: Watches of local variables]

Can someone please explain me why entire `in` array gets filled by `0xFF`(255) bytes and why `tmp` is not equal it's estimated value?

Tips about how to improve above code to fill `in` array with correct hex values also welcome.

Comment: Get rid of the casts. `(unsigned char *)` is unnecessary. `(size_t)` is unnecessary as the return type of `strlen()` already is `size_t`. And `(const char *)argv[2] + i, &argv[2] + 2` is just wrong.

Comment: The second argument for `strtol` is quite wrong - nothing to do with the input string. And I suggest your loop should be to `strlen(...)` not `strlen(...)/2`, if you are aiming to try converting the input string several times, skipping the first pair, next pair, etc of hex digits.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is erroneous for multiple counts and the casts hide the problems:

Casting the return value of `malloc` is not necessary in C and can potentially hide an unsafe conversion if you forget to include `<stdlib.h>`:

```
in = (unsigned char *)malloc(16);
```

Casting the return value of `strlen` to `(size_t)` is useless, even redundant as `strlen` is defined to return a `size_t`.  Again you might have forgotten to include `<string.h>`...

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < (size_t)strlen(argv[2]) / 2; i += 2) {
    long tmp = 0;
```

`strtol` takes a const pointer to `char`, which `argv[2] + i` will convert to implicitly.  The cast `(const char*)` is useless.  The second argument is the address of a `char*`.  You pass the address of the fifth element of `argv`, in other terms `&argv[4]`, most certainly not what you indent to do, although your loop's purpose is quite obscure...

```
    tmp = strtol((const char *)argv[2] + i, &argv[2] + 2, 16);
```

Copying the long value in `tmp` with `memcpy` would require to copy `sizeof(tmp)` bytes.  Copying the *first* byte only has an implementation defined effect, depending on the size of `char` and the endianness of the target system:

```
    memcpy(&in[i], &tmp, 1);
}
```

You should post a complete compilable example that illustrates your problem, a code fragment is missing important context information, such as what header files are included, how variables are defined and what code is executed before the fragment.

As written, your code does not make much sense, trying to interpret its behavior is pointless.

Regarding the question in reference, your code does not even remotely provide a solution for converting a string of hexadecimal characters to an array of bytes.