# How to convert a string to hexadecimal array in c?

Tags: hex

I need to convert an hexadecimal string to hexadecimal array. For eg:, 083ce6e3b9744adcd729ee9935158a77 is hexastring and i would like to convert this to an array and save to a variable like {0X08,0X3c,0Xe6,0Xe3,0Xb9,0X74,0X4a,0Xdc,0Xd7,0X29,0Xee,0X99,0X35,0X15,0X8a,0X77}
Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correctly convert a Hex String to Byte Array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267803/how-to-correctly-convert-a-hex-string-to-byte-array-in-c)

Comment: Thank you BeyelerStudio, for your reply.