# Qt equivalent of Perl pack/unpack

Tags: perl, qt, hex

The following is a list of hex data and the float numbers it represents:

```
e77ed8f8201a5440 = 78.4083
0000000000005540 = 82
4c541773e2185040 = 62.3888
0000000000005640 = 86
```

The following Perl code uses pack/unpack to gets the conversion almost right (out by exactly 2):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>)
{
   chomp;
   my $dat = $_;
   my $hval = pack "H*", $dat;
   my $fval = unpack "F", $hval;
   print "$dat .. $fval \n";
}

__DATA__
e77ed8f8201a5440
0000000000005540
4c541773e2185040
0000000000005640
```

Output:

```
e77ed8f8201a5440 .. 80.408262454435
0000000000005540   .. 84
4c541773e2185040  .. 64.3888213851762
0000000000005640 .. 88
```

What is the Qt/C equivalent of this pack/unpack, or what is the algorithm it is use to "convert" the hex to float so I can that up instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the Qt/C equivalent of this pack/unpack,

```
#include <QString>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

...

QString value="e77ed8f8201a5440";
// convert the hex string to an array of bytes
QByteArray arr=QByteArray::fromHex(value);
// reverse if necessary
#if Q_BYTE_ORDER==Q_BIG_ENDIAN
std::reverse(arr.begin(), arr.end());
#endif
// if everything went right, copy the bytes in a double
if(arr.size()==sizeof(double))
{
    double out;
    std::memcpy((void *)&out, (void *)arr.data(), sizeof(double));
    // ...
}
```

Maybe you could also get away with QtEndian (instead of conditionally calling `std::reverse` over `arr`), but it's not clear if those functions can be called on anything but integral types.

> or what is the algorithm it is use to "convert" the hex to float so I can that up instead?

The data you have is just the dump of the raw content of a little-endian IEEE-754 `double`; the "algorithm" is simply decoding the hexadecimal to the bytes it represents and copying them to a `double` variable (reversing the byte order if we are on a big-endian machine).

Comment: @ikegami: uh sorry, you are right, I don't know why I continued to think they were floats.

Comment: Thanks - the data I am reading is from a QByteArray so this answers is exactly what I need. Many thanks.

Comment: @TenG: in that case, keep in mind that, if your `QByteArray` contains more stuff than just one single `double`, the `reverse` must be applied on 8-byte chunks (and not on the whole QByteArray`).

Answer (score 1):

`pack 'H*'` is the [conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3408706/589924) from hex character pairs to the corresponding bytes.

`unpack 'F'` is a cast to a `double`. This can be done using `memcpy` (to avoid alignment issues), as shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   char bytes[] = { 0xE7, 0x7e, 0xd8, 0xf8, 0x20, 0x1a, 0x54, 0x40 };

   double d;
   memcpy(&d, bytes, sizeof(bytes));

   printf("%lf\n", d);
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc -o a a.c && a
80.408262
```

Note that this will fail on big-endian machines. You'll have to reverse the bytes before copying them on those machines.

Comment: This is C. I don't know what `Qt` is.

Comment: Thanks - this is a great help. I don't understand how it works but I can solve that later.