# I can't understand how to convert hex string to unsigned char in C?

Tags: c, type-conversion, hex, unsigned-char

I have input

```
unsigned char hex[64] =  9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a0"
```

and I want output like this:

```
unsigned char tmpInHash[32] = { 0x9f, 0x86, 0xd0, 0x81, 0x88, 0x4c, 0x7d, 0x65, 0x9a, 0x2f, 0xea, 0xa0, 0xc5, 0x5a, 0xd0, 0x15, 0xa3, 0xbf, 0x4f, 0x1b, 0x2b, 0x0b, 0x82, 0x2c, 0xd1, 0x5d, 0x6c, 0x15, 0xb0, 0xf0, 0x0a, 0x08 }
```

I searched for the answer everywhere, but the answers , which I found, do not fit.

**EDIT**

I want that when I write:

```
for(i=0; i< strlen(tmpInHash); i++ {
    printf("%c ", tmpInHash);
}
```

I get this:

```
0x9f 0x86 0xd0 0x81 0x88 0x4c 0x7d 0x65 0x9a ...
```

Is it possible?

Comment: One way is to make a loop, using `sscanf` with the `%x2X` format string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408706/hexadecimal-string-to-byte-array-in-c is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Mean you using standard functions or with your own code?

Comment: @M.M, I did it, maybe i did wrong     for (int i = 0; i<hashedDataLen; i++){
sscanf(&tmpInHash[i], "%02x", hex[i]);}

Comment: @LPs, it doesn't matter ;)

Comment: @mary skip 2 characters at a time in the input

Comment: @M.M: If scanning into  `char` array the format string should be `"%02hhx"`.

Comment: From looking the expected result I feel `hex` is missing a trailing `8`.

Comment: @alk Yes, and the buffer should be `65` chars long

Comment: @LPs depending on code used to scan, size 64 is OK too.

Comment: @mary `sscanf(&tmpInHash[i], "%02x", hex[i]);}` --> `sscanf(&tmpInHash[i*2], "%02hhx", &hex[i]);}`  `(hh, &, *2)`

Comment: Note: `strlen(tmpInHash)` requires `tmpInHash[]` to have a null charterer.

Comment: @chux well, but `printf("%s\n", hex);` is around the corner. ;)

Comment: Your expected output cannot be printed using `printf("%c ", tmpInHash[i])` Hex code wants `%x` format specifier, so `printf("0x%x ", tmpInHash[i])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to convert this is the following way:

- Iterate through every item of the string, where every 2 characters represent a number.
- Break out each such character pair and store them in a temporary string: `char tmp {str[i], str[i+1], '\0'};`.
- Call `strtol(tmp, NULL, 16)` on this string to get the integer number.

Answer (score 1):

Without "high level" functions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char hex[] = "9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08";

    size_t stringLength = (sizeof(hex)/sizeof(hex[0]))-1;

    unsigned char tmpInHash[stringLength/2];

    int j=0;

    // reset the char to 0. This grants that next or operation works on reset buffer
    tmpInHash[0] = 0;

    // loop that parse the whole string
    for (size_t i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
    {
        // check if the char is a to f
        if ((hex[i] >= 'a') && (hex[i] <= 'f'))
        {
            tmpInHash[j] |= hex[i] -'a' + 10;
        }
        // che if is a digit
        else if ((hex[i] >= '0') && (hex[i] <= '9'))
        {
            tmpInHash[j] |= hex[i] -'0';
        }
        // character not allowed
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Character not allowed: %c position: %zu\n", hex[i], i);
            return 1;
        }

        // even index chars are hig 4 bits of unsigned char
        if ((i%2) == 0)
        {
            tmpInHash[j]<<=4;
        }
        else
        {
            // nex unsigned char
            j++;

            // reset the char to 0. This grants that next or operation works on reset buffer
            if (j < stringLength/2)
               tmpInHash[j] = 0;
        }

    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < stringLength/2; i++)
    {
        printf("0x%02X ", tmpInHash[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");


    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
0x9F 0x86 0xD0 0x81 0x88 0x4C 0x7D 0x65 0x9A 0x2F 0xEA 0xA0 0xC5 0x5A 0xD0 0x15 0xA3 0xBF 0x4F 0x1B 0x2B 0x0B 0x82 0x2C 0xD1 0x5D 0x6C 0x15 0xB0 0xF0 0x0A 0x08
```

**EDIT**
Another example can be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned char hex[] = "9f86d081884g7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08";

#define HEX_LEN (sizeof(hex)-1)

unsigned char tmpInHash[HEX_LEN/2]={0};

int main(void)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = 0;

    // parse all charcaters of hex
    while(hex[i] != '\0')
    {
        // check if the char is a to f
        if ((hex[i] >= 'a') && (hex[i] <= 'f'))
        {
            tmpInHash[j] |= hex[i] -'a' + 10;
        }
        // che if is a digit
        else if ((hex[i] >= '0') && (hex[i] <= '9'))
        {
            tmpInHash[j] |= hex[i] -'0';
        }
        // character not allowed
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Character not allowed: %c position: %zu\n", hex[i], i);
            return 1;
        }

        // even index chars are hig 4 bits of unsigned char
        if ((i%2) == 0)
        {
            tmpInHash[j]<<=4;
        }
        else
        {
            // nex unsigned char
            j++;
        }

        // next hex char
        i++;
    }

    // print loop
    for (i = 0; i < (HEX_LEN/2); i++)
    {
        printf("0x%02X ", tmpInHash[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work... I got 20000+ symbols like this ���������������������������

Comment: @mary My code works well, as you can see [HERE](http://ideone.com/1UtqM2)

Comment: @LPs I'm sorry,yes, it works. i made a mistake ;) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char hex[64] =  "9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a0";
 unsigned char *ptrHex =hex;
    unsigned char tmpInHash[32];
    int i ,tmp ;
    for(i=0 ; i < 32 ; i++)
    {
         if((*ptrHex)<=9 && (*ptrHex) >=0)
                  tmp=(*ptrHex)-'0';
         else tmp=(*ptrHex)-'a'+10;
         tmpInHash[i]=(tmp<<4);
         ptrHex++;

       if((*ptrHex)<=9 && (*ptrHex) >=0)
                  tmp=(*ptrHex)-'0';
         else tmp=(*ptrHex)-'a'+10;

         tmpInHash[i]|=tmp ;
         ptrHex++;
    }
```

Comment: `tmp=(*ptrHex)-'a';` certainly is wrong.    Consider `tmp=(*ptrHex)-'a' + 10;`  Even that has weaknesses

Comment: @chux you mean the weakness if the letters were upper cases ?

Comment: Case is one issue.  A pedantic corner is that C does not specify that `a`, `b`, etc are consecutive.  Yet `a-f` are consecutive in ASCII (99.99%+ of encodings) and [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) (99%+ of remainder)