# How to interpret an unsigned char array as hex array?

Tags: c, arrays, char, hex, checksum

I have a unsigned char array of which I'd like to calculate the CRC32 checksum.

The CRC32 function also expects a unsigned char pointer, however, it interprets the array as an ASCII array.

This is the CRC function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned int crc32(unsigned char *message) 
{
   int i, j;
   unsigned int byte, crc, mask;

   i = 0;
   crc = 0xFFFFFFFF;
   while (message[i] != 0) {
      byte = message[i];            // Get next byte.
      crc = crc ^ byte;
      for (j = 7; j >= 0; j--) {    // Do eight times.
         mask = -(crc & 1);
         crc = (crc >> 1) ^ (0xEDB88320 & mask);
      }
      i = i + 1;
   }
   return ~crc;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned char *arr;
    if ((arr = malloc(64)) == NULL) {
        perror("Could not allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char str[] = "47d46d17e759a1dec810758c08004510002127d90000401152e4c0a8b21fc0a8b2255b9b5b9c000db20caabbccddee00000000000000000000000000";
    memcpy(arr, str, strlen(str));
    // ...
    unsigned int crc = crc32(arr);
    printf("CRC: 0x%x\n", crc); // 0xB6BA014A instead of 0xBF6B57A2

    return 0;
}
```

Now, I'd like to calculate the CRC32 but the unsigned char array has to be interpreted as an hex array.

F.ex., this is the result of the calculated CRC: 
Input:
`"47d46d17e759a1dec810758c08004510002127d90000401152e4c0a8b21fc0a8b2255b9b5b9c000db20caabbccddee00000000000000000000000000"`

- as ASCII: 0xB6BA014A (this is what I usually get because it's interpreted as ASCII)
- as Hex.: 0xBF6B57A2 (this is the checksum I want)

Comment: It sounds like you are reading your input as a string rather than converting each pair of characters to the number the hex value represents. Hard to say without a [mcve], but it seems like you're just passing the wrong data to the function.

Comment: What you want to do is convert the hexadecimal numeral in `str` to data in a new array of `unsigned char`, which you can then pass to `crc32`.

Comment: Ok. Then my question is how to achieve that in a swift way.

Comment: Create a new array of the required size. Examine the characters in `str`. You may wish to examine them in pairs. For each character, prepare the four bits it represents when interpreted as a hexadecimal digit. Put those bits into `str`. (If you do that two characters at a time, you will be putting eight bits into the new array at a time, which is generally more convenient.) If you do it this way, you will need to modify `crc32` to take the length as a separate parameter instead of deducing it from a null byte (since a null byte is valid data).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hexadecimal string to byte array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408706/hexadecimal-string-to-byte-array-in-c)

Comment: Also     `memcpy(arr, str, sizeof(str));` --> `memcpy(arr, str, strlen(str));
` as `sizeof(str)` is `sizeof of pointer`.

Comment: Alternately, you can do the hexadecimal conversion inside `crc32`: Examine the characters in `message` two at a time. For each character, prepare the four bits it represents as a hexadecimal digit. Put the two four-bit values together to make one eight-bit value, and use that in the CRC.

Comment: It seems like you only want to test the crc function.  The problem is that the way you initialize the array.  If you want the arrary to be initialized not as a string but as binary data it needs to be in the form of, for example, `arr[32] = { 0x47, 0xd4, ... )'`

Comment: I can't change that. The array will always be initialized as non-binary.

Comment: Per @EricPostpischil suggestion, then you have to change the line `byte = message[i];` to not use the ASCII value but the byte value.  See the Hexadecimal string question on how to use `sscanf()`.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "HEX"-array or an "ASCII"-array.

Comment: True. I did't know how to express that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to interpret an unsigned char array as hex array?

- Convert each pair of hexadecimal characters in the string to a byte value.  Code below converts via a *compound literal* to form a 3 byte *string*, followed by a call to `strtoul()`.

  ```
  //                    v----------------------------------v _compound literal_
  arr2[i / 2] = strtoul((char[3]) {str[i], str[i + 1], '\0'}, 0, 16);
  ```

  More advanced code would test for the unexpected presence of non-hexadecimal characters or an odd/zero length.

---

CRC calculation changes needed

- Change CRC calculation to a length based one rather than a string one.

  ```
  // unsigned int crc32(const char *)
  unsigned int crc32(const void *m, size_t len)
  ```

  Although not coded below, consider `uint32_t` instead of `unsigned int` in `crc32()` for correct operation when `unsigned` is not 32-bit.

---

Altogether

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned int crc32(const void *m, size_t len) {
  const unsigned char *message = m;
  size_t i;
  int j;
  unsigned int byte, crc, mask;

  i = 0;
  crc = 0xFFFFFFFF;
  //while (message[i] != 0) {
  while (i < len) {
    byte = message[i];            // Get next byte.
    crc = crc ^ byte;
    for (j = 7; j >= 0; j--) {    // Do eight times.
      mask = -(crc & 1);
      crc = (crc >> 1) ^ (0xEDB88320 & mask);
    }
    i = i + 1;
  }
  return ~crc;
}
```

Sample usage

```
int main() {
  char str[] =
      "47d46d17e759a1dec810758c08004510002127d90000401152e4c0a8b21fc0a8b2255b9b5b9c000db20caabbccddee00000000000000000000000000";
  size_t len = strlen(str);
  unsigned int crc = crc32(str, len);
  printf("CRC: 0x%X\n", crc); // 0xB6BA014A instead of 0xBF6B57A2

  size_t len2 = (len + 1) / 2;
  unsigned char arr2[len2];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
    arr2[i / 2] = strtoul((char[3]) {str[i], str[i + 1], '\0'}, 0, 16);
  }
  crc = crc32(arr2, len2);
  printf("CRC: 0x%X\n", crc); // 0xB6BA014A instead of 0xBF6B57A2

  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
CRC: 0xB6BA014A
CRC: 0xBF6B57A2
```

---

OP original code had undefined behavior in that it looked for a *null character* with `while (message[i] != 0) {`, yet `memcpy(arr, str, strlen(str));` failed to provide one.

Comment: Where did you hide the lookup table?

Comment: You must be clever, that's a nice answer. I appreciate that.

Comment: @Swordfish Unclear, what  _lookup table_ do you mean?

Comment: @Swordfish The `for (j = 7; j >= 0; j--) {` does that.  Usual trade-off of speed vs code/data size.

Comment: @chux *does that* – ah.