# How to resolve GCC compilation [-Wformat] warning?

Tags: c, scanf, compiler-warnings, conversion-specifier

I am using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408706/hexadecimal-string-to-byte-array-in-c) to convert hex string to byte array.The code is works correct.
While compiling this code I am getting below compilation warning. Is there any way I can resolve it?

```
/* test.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./test <input hex string>\n");
        return 0;
    }

    char *hexstring = argv[1];
    printf("hextring:%s\n", hexstring);
    uint8_t str_len = strlen(hexstring);
    printf("length:%d\n", str_len);
    uint8_t array_size = str_len / 2;
    printf("array_size:%d\n", array_size);
    uint8_t *input = (uint8_t *)calloc(array_size, sizeof(uint8_t));

   for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
   {
       sscanf(hexstring, "%02x", &input[i]);
       hexstring = hexstring + 2;
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
   {
       printf("input[%d]:[%.2x]\n", i, input[i]);
   }
return 0;
}
```

Compilation warning:

```
gcc test.c -o test
test.c:24:34: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int *' but the argument has type 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *') [-Wformat]
    sscanf(hexstring, "%02x", &input[i]);
                       ~~~~   ^~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: `format specifies type 'unsigned int *' but the argument has type 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *')` At what point in the above message things become unclear?

Comment: at this line:       sscanf(hexstring, "%02x", &input[I]) @n.m.

Comment: @raj123 n.m is telling you that the warning tells you exactly what's wrong. You're using the wrong specifier.

Comment: That I know its required unsigned int*  however I am using uint8_t. I need a way to resolve it without modifying input buffer type as input buffer is hex byte so I am using uint8_t*. @klutt

Comment: @raj123 Have you read the documentation for scanf format string?

Comment: I got it thanks.@klutt

Comment: I just typecasted uint8*t to unsigned int* while pasing in scantf

Comment: @raj123 That's VERY wrong

Comment: Well the obvious way is to use something other than your buffer. How about `int c; sscanf(hexstring, "%02x", &c);`? You now have something you can probably put in the buffer somehow. Another way is outlined in the answer.

Comment: "I just typecasted uint8*t to unsigned int*". This is undefined behaviour. You cannot just throw casts at problems and hope they go away.

Comment: Ok thanks got it .Answer given by @MikeCAT is the proper solution for that@n.m.

Comment: The simpler solution, which the `scanf` documentation should have showed you, is `%hhx`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of `uint8_t` is usually small than one of `unsigned int`, so your code seems *happened to work*.

You should use correct format specifer.

Add

```
#include <inttypes.h>
```

at the beginning of your code and change the format `"%02x"` to `"%02" SCNx8`.

The `SCNx8` macro will be expanded to correct format specifier and connected to the `"%02"` part.

If unfortunately this is not supported in your environment, another way is to use a buffer with correct type to read the value.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
   {
       unsigned int buffer = 0;
       sscanf(hexstring, "%02x", &buffer);
       input[i] = (uint8_t)buffer;
       hexstring = hexstring + 2;
   }
```

Comment: A simpler solution is `%hhx`.