# Easiest way to convert a char* of hex to actual hex in C?

Tags: c

I have a `char*` of user input hex digits that I want to convert to actual hex (`u8_t` type) to be able to be used in an i2c command.

Example:
Input: `char* = 55` and I want to be able to use this as `0x55` in my i2c command so it has to be in hex format (My command looks like `i2c_write(u8_t addr, blah, blah)` so I would use it like `i2c_write(0x55, blah, blah)`. Does anyone know how to change it? I've looked at resources online and I can only find how to convert it to an `int`.

Comment: what is "actual" hex? If you convert it to an int then just use the low order byte of the int

Comment: First, u8_t **is** an (8 bit, unsigned) int. Anyway, there are plenty of answer online, including here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408706/hexadecimal-string-to-byte-array-in-c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hexadecimal string to byte array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408706/hexadecimal-string-to-byte-array-in-c)

Comment: Shouldn't this  `char* = 55` read  `char* = "55"`?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I figured it out by using `strtol(<char array>, NULL, 16)`