# how to get md5sum command and get the string output in code

Tags: c++, linux, unix

I'm writing a code in C++ and I wish to get the md5 checksum of a certain string.
I know I can run `system("echo "myStirng" | md5sum > some_file.txt")` and then read the file.
I'm writing code for an embedded system and due to performance issues I don't wan't to use file operations. also, I can't use any openSSL functions in my code.
I did my searching and all the answers I came across either included some file operations or used openSSL functions.
Is there a way to get the md5 checksum without using file operations and without using openSSL? maybe running the linux command md5sum as a different process from the code like the C function `system` does, but returning the checksum hex string and not the return code.

Thanks you.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395690/md5sum-of-file-in-linux-c

Comment: @slugonamission this solution will require me to download and install openSSL, is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: @eladm26 Why would it require you to download/install openSSL? You should just be able to link it like so: `-lssl -lcrypto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a proof of concept I wrote some time ago. Pretty much like the second answer in the link in @slugonmission 's comment but a bit better I think (using `fread`). Actually at the end I preferred the approach using the library as a little bit faster. So I suggest if dependency on openssl is ok with you and performance is important to prefer the library.

```
FILE* pipe = popen("md5sum /home/bla.txt", "r");                                                                                       
if (pipe != NULL)                                                                                                                                                    
{                                                                                                                                                     
  static const unsigned md5size = 32;                                                                                                                 
  unsigned char md5res[md5size + 1];                                                                                                                  
  int readSize = fread((void*) md5res, sizeof(char), md5size, pipe);                                                                                  
  if (readSize != md5size)                                                                                                                            
  {                                                                                                                                                    
      std::cout << "Error reading md5" << std::endl;                                                                                                     
      return 1;                                                                                                                                          
  }                                                                                                                                                    
  pclose(pipe);                                                                                                                        
  md5res[md5size] = 0;    
 }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but this answer includes files, do you think there is option to solve it without using files, maybe using md5sum linux command somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Use http://hashlib2plus.sourceforge.net/ then run something like:

```
#include <hashlibpp.h>
#include <string>

int main() {
    hashwrapper *rap = new md5wrapper();
    std::string hash = rap->getHashFromFile("README.TXT");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but I can't use this library.