# How to calculate the MD5 of a char* using C++

Tags: c++, md5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C++, How to get MD5 hash of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220046/in-c-how-to-get-md5-hash-of-a-file)

I am currently using Ubuntu and am wishing to calculate the MD5 of a `char*`. was wondering if there is a pre-installed library that would just need including, or would I have to download a specially designed one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include `openssl/MD5.h` and use the following to calculate the hash

```
MD5(<characters>, <length of it>, <the result(pointer)>);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [hashlib++](http://hashlib2plus.sourceforge.net/) or [Crypto API](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/cryptest.aspx).

Comment: Also recommend hashlib++ (if only for hashing)

Answer (score -3):

I would rephrase the question. In the context of C++, you're asking for the MD5 sum of a single pointer to char, which is practically meaningless.

That 'char *' could refer to a location in memory that refers to the file content you are after, in which case you're going to need a size somewhere, or it could refer to a null-terminated string, or a pascal-string, or, really, anything else.

With ubuntu, I'd do something like 'apt-cache search md5' and see what you get.  On my debian system, libgcrypt11 looks intriguing.

Comment: Most C/C++ programmers understand that normally char * refers to a NULL terminated string. It could mean other things but no need to be so pedantic.

Comment: Actually, in C++, it probably more often refers to an arbituary chunk of memory - a 'char' being used as a generic byte type. One would normally use std::string instead. This is C++, not C.

Comment: And don't forget, I actually show how to find this information yourself, ie, make use of the package manager - AND, I give a promising result that could be useful.