# Is there any function to get the md5sum value of file in linux?

Tags: linux, openssl, md5sum

I want to compute the md5sum value of a file ,not a string . I found somebody had used openssl md5 function. But it's only used in string . Is there any function that i can use to get the md5sum value of a file which equals using md5sum command in linux.

Comment: Check the code of md5sum or use md5 lib.
1. Read file and save it in a buf
2. Use md5 lib to convert the string -> md5 digest
3. check the below link on how to use MD5API
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627723/how-to-create-a-md5-hash-of-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 4):

You can generate md5sum using **openssl/md5.h**
Please refer [How to get the MD5 hash of a file in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220046/in-c-how-to-get-md5-hash-of-a-file)

In this link example is provided for generating md5sum of file using openssl

Also you can use following commands in Linux to generate md5sum of file

```
openssl dgst -md5 yourfile
md5sum yourfile
```