# interrupt c code, md5 file

Tags: c, hash

How can I interrupt a running C code, to create a hash of a file in a directory?

So at some point in the C code, I put in some code which will create an md5 hash of a file, such as thisfile.txt?

Comment: If I understand correclty try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220046/in-c-how-to-get-md5-hash-of-a-file

Comment: What OS are you working with?

Answer (score 1):

The two parts of your question seem un-related.
If you want to interrupt a running C code, you should use signals. Refer http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/signals.html

If you want to create md5, use MD5 APIs which are readily available.

I don't understand the need to generate an interrupt to calculate the hash.
Thanks

Comment: It depends on the OS. If it is Windows, signals are not available. One solution is then [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686915(v=vs.85).aspx) by checking if the event is signaled (by another portion of code, maybe a callback or another thread)

Comment: I did not realise that C did not have a native md5 hashing capability. Does it have any native hashing ability?

Comment: @user1463479 See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library for an overview of C's standard library. It's way smaller and more low-level than what you'd expect from most so-called "scripting" languages. And that's how we like it! :D