# MD5 of a file have HANDLE hFile

Tags: c++, md5

I have a HANDLE of a file, hFile.
I want to find its MD5,
How can I? I just need a little guidance.

```
HANDLE hFile=myClass.getHandle();
calculateMd5(hFile);
calculatemMd5(HANDLE hFile)
{
...???
}
```

Comment: you might want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220046/in-c-how-to-get-md5-hash-of-a-file

Answer (score 1):

[Example C Program: Creating an MD5 Hash from File Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382380%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I have seen this already. but where can I find winencrpyt.dll after including winencrpyt.h?

Comment: You need to use `wincrypt.h` header and `crypt32.lib` library

Comment: When I include wincrypt.h, should I add crypt32.lib explicitly?
because I'm getting link error.
and how to add crypt32.lib in Qt project?

Comment: @NoorNawaz yes, you should all it explicitly. Check how to add external libraries at Qt projects [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718447/adding-external-library-into-qt-creator-project).