# visual studio doenst recognize md5 functions in c++

Tags: c++, encryption, md5

heyy, I want to encrypt string by using md5 class.
BUT the problem is that I dont know how to use it at all :(
visual studio doenst recognize this class or her function.
what can I do in order to use md5 encryption?
thanks

Comment: first of all, md5 isn't an encryption scheme. secondly, you're going to need a library or framework that calculates the md5 because the standard c++ libraries don't provide it. Show us any code you're trying to use

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the MD5 hash of a file in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220046/how-to-get-the-md5-hash-of-a-file-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Install Openssl ExE and set path in your system env variables or MSVC APP and build the code

Comment: I download crypto++, isn't it enough?