# To implement MD5 hash on a char array containg both hex and char

Tags: c++, visual-c++

**Structure**

In the `source folder`, there's the `test.cpp`

In the `Header Files folder`, there's the `test.h`

I'm trying to implement `md5 hash function` on a char array `unsigned char dat[39]` that contain both hex and char

referencing the example in [How to get the MD5 hash of a file in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220046/how-to-get-the-md5-hash-of-a-file-in-c)

As I **cannot include** `<openssl/md5.h>`, hence I manually add a md5.h from

> www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-md5-function

to the `Header Files folder`

Then in the test.h file, I have added the function

```
oid print_md5_sum(unsigned char* md) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i <39; i++) {
        printf("%02x",md[i]);
    }
```

After that, in the test.cpp file, I try to implement the md5 function

```
print_md5_sum(dat);
```

The project can compile, but the md5 function cannot work. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The data in a `char[]` is just data. Doesn't matter what the data is.

Comment: "but the md5 function cannot work" That's not a helpful problem description. What happens when you try to use it?